# Mapping a JSON object to a knockout array using mapping plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

```
function PanelViewVM() {
var self = this;

self.PanelName = ko.observable("Test");
self.PanelDetails = ko.observableArray([]),

self.SelectPanel = function () {

    $.ajax("/DPanel/FillIndex", {

        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {

            ko.mapping.fromJS(data.PanelDetails, {}, self.PanelDetails);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

};



self.SelectPanel();
};

ko.applyBindings(new PanelViewVM());
```

JSON ajax response is:

```
{
"PanelDetails": [
    {
        "PanelID": 466,
        "Panel": "581ZDPAD30D",
        "PanelType": 2,
        "Source": "S63B",
        "Substation": "S63",
        "Bay": "615W",
        "Voltage": 480,
        "kVA": 630,
        "Utility": "N",
        "Train": "B",
        "Circuits": 12,
        "Status": "Existing/Re-fed/Re-tag",
        "Drawing": "IRAE-0326"
    }
],
"DPanelCcts": [
    {
        "PanCctID": 1442,
        "PanelID": 466,
        "cct": 1,
        "Base": 250,
        "POCID": null,
        "DateUpdated": null,
        "Assigned": ""
    },
    {
        "PanCctID": 1443,
        "PanelID": 466,
        "cct": 2,
        "Base": 400,
        "POCID": 38,
        "DateUpdated": "/Date(1427842800000)/",
        "Assigned": "EDT113-E04"
    }
] }
```

in the map, I am trying to return the PanelDetails objects to a knockout array.

and select Panel from that array and bind to the strong tag

```
    <p>
        Panel: <strong data-bind=" text: PanelDetails[0].Panel">

</strong>
    </p>
```

I don't think I am passing to the array correctly.
In the case of the PanelDetails Array, it will only have one row of data.

Comment: PanelDetails is an observableArray. You need to use function notation before indexing: `<strong data-bind=" text: PanelDetails()[0].Panel">`

Comment: That doesn't seem to have worked. there might be a problem in the way that I am binding data to the array `self.PanelDetails = ko.observableArray([])'` is it bound correctly in the statement  `ko.mapping.fromJS(data.PanelDetails, {}, self.PanelDetails);` ?

Comment: @RoyJ mention was right . here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24780/ . let you know if you are looking for something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a Fiddle to test this. If you're right about how the Ajax data comes back, the only thing you need to do is change your bind variable notation.

```
Panel: <strong data-bind=" text: PanelDetails()[0].Panel">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jgm5zy0a/

Comment: I have another issue now. when I bind to a second element in the DOM it only binds the first from the array.    `Panel: <strong data-bind=" text: PanelDetails()[0].Panel"></strong>
        Source: <strong data-bind=" text: PanelDetails()[0].Source"></strong>
        Substation: <strong data-bind=" text: PanelDetails()[0].Substation"></strong>
        Bay: <strong data-bind=" text: PanelDetails()[0].Bay"></strong>` it seems to work fine in your fiddle but not in my environment.

Comment: @user1781272 it should work . Apart from that i really advice to follow a better approach create `mappings` later try not using indexes in view . cheers